# Reading data from a file in Java

Tags: java, file-io

So I have a background in c++ and I am trying to learn java. Everything is pretty similar. I am having a problem thought with file i/o. So I am messing around and doing really simple programs to get the basic ideas. Here is my code to read data from a file. So I am reading Core Java Volume 1 by Cay Hortsman and it tells me to write this to read from a file,

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(Paths.get("myFile.txt");
```

But when I write it in my code, it gives me a red line under paths.  So I am not sure how to read from a file.  It does not go into much detail about the subject.  So my program below I am trying to just read numbers in from a file and store them in an array.

```
 package practice.with.arrays.and.io;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.nio.file.Path;
 import java.util.*;

 public class PracticeWithArraysAndIO 
 {

     static final int TEN = 10;

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
      //Declaring a scanner object to read in data
      Scanner in = new Scanner(Paths.get("myFile.txt"));

      //Declaring an array to store the data from the file
      int[] arrayOfInts = new int[TEN];

      //Local variable to store data in from the file
      int data = 0;

      try
      {
      for(int i = 0; i < TEN; i++)
      {
          data = in.nextInt();
          arrayOfInts[i] = data;
      }
      }
      finally
      {
       in.close();
      }
  }
```

Comment: You are first having an error with your syntax. Your example statement is missing a close paren.  If that does not resolve your issue, allow your IDE to declare the necessary library definitions.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @TonyEnnis, The code he wrote in the larger code block is not missing the closing `)`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why you are doing `Paths.get(filename))`.

You can wrap a `Scanner` around a file like this. As the comments below mention, you should choose an appropriate `charset` for your file.

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("myFile.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

To use the constant above, you need the following import, and Java 7.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
```

Comment: That's a great way to mess up non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @bmargulies, Please clarify.

Comment: Never use an API that opens a file without accepting a character set name, because then you are at the mercy of the default encoding, which is often wrong. Please advise the use of an InputStreamReader, passing, explicitly, the desired charset.

Comment: There is a constructor in `Scanner` that takes `Path` as argument.

Comment: @bmargulies Or use the overloaded constructor `Scanner(File source, String charsetName)`.

Comment: I just did that Paths thing because that is how they told me to write it in the Core Java book.   The book did not elaborate on fileio.   So I was kind of lost.

Comment: @bmargulies, Updated. Or do you prefer that I write `UTF-8` instead to avoid Java 7 dependency?

Answer (score 1):

With my experience in Java, I've used the BufferedReader class for reading a text file instead of the Scanner. I usually reserve the Scanner class for user input in a terminal. Perhaps you could try this method out.

Create a BufferedReader with FileReader like so:

```
BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt"));
```

After setting this up, you can read lines with:

```
stringName = buffReader.readLine();
```

This example will set the String, stringName, to the first line in your document. To continue reading more lines, you'll need to create a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the BufferedReader class.
I hope it is helpful for you

```
public class PracticeWithArraysAndIO {

static final int TEN = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try{


        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/myFile.txt"));//input your file path

        int value=0;

        int[] arrayOfInts = new int[TEN];

        int i=0;

        while((value = br.read()) != -1) 
        { 
            if(i == 10)  //if out of index, break
                break;

            char c = (char)value; //convert value to char
            int number = Character.getNumericValue(c); //convert char to int

            arrayOfInts[i] = number; //insert number into array

            i++;
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(br != null)
            br.close(); //buffer close
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `java.nio.file.Paths`.